# Parsing a JSON list into a normal string in Python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a JSON list which has this data:

```
[ "B6y2z5jqUeFXJAre8ugXkHeYX87SU3hi6E", "B9bUMF8VLbj8r2b8uEQ7TY4R6TRDCjjhMV", "BJauzhHkcLKLdFsMuqLh6QrFGCTJjC7RQz", "BLcwoAVZNSLXLBMqQ7PQqEDFhN4owFLJo2", "BMaqYvfgrcZf6Wx1P3P8oBQzwjEHqGAEgy", "BMsXoM73RoxjwCVqbySNPcrVCKQqbLFn12", "BR5ptgmfcYceqka6JLxqkr21ce8J5T6Cvv" ]
```

I want to take the first thing in the list (`"B6y2z5jqUeFXJAre8ugXkHeYX87SU3hi6E"`) and turn it into a normal Python string. How can I do this?

Comment: `json.loads(payload)[0]` contains the first element if `payload` is a string which contains a JSON list.

Comment: json.loads(json_string)[0]?

Comment: So where is this `json` list? Is it in a file? Have you received it still as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already a string. You can do:

```py
# IF:
json_data = [ "B6y2z5jqUeFXJAre8ugXkHeYX87SU3hi6E", "B9bUMF8VLbj8r2b8uEQ7TY4R6TRDCjjhMV", "BJauzhHkcLKLdFsMuqLh6QrFGCTJjC7RQz", "BLcwoAVZNSLXLBMqQ7PQqEDFhN4owFLJo2", "BMaqYvfgrcZf6Wx1P3P8oBQzwjEHqGAEgy", "BMsXoM73RoxjwCVqbySNPcrVCKQqbLFn12", "BR5ptgmfcYceqka6JLxqkr21ce8J5T6Cvv" ]

element_one = json_data[0]
element_two = json_data[1]
```

The list is a list of strings, and they can be accessed with that.